# Using Inputbox Value to Create Chart Title in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros, inputbox

Question:

You will need to create three variables as below:

"rangeData": it's to store the currently selected range.
   "titleChart": it's to store chart title
   "nameSheet" : it's to store sheet name

You will use the `InputBox` function twice to get a title for the chart and a name for the worksheet, and use the title given for the chart and the name given for the worksheet.

SO far I have been stuck with getting the value from the `InputBox` to the new chart title:

Code I have so far:

```
Dim RangeData As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Dim ctInputbox As String
Dim CT As ChartTitle

Dim nsnInputbox As String
Dim nsn As Worksheet

'Change Data source to currentley selected cells
Set rng = Selection

'Add a chart onto the active sheet and select the chart
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

'Chart type is Clustered Column chart
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

'Assign a chart title:

'instead of using the content of cell H13 as the chart title, ask
'the user for the title of the chart and set the title

'Add user data to create a chart title    
ctInputbox = InputBox("Please enter a chart title", "Chart Title Name")
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True

With ActiveChart.ChartObjects
    Set CT = ctInputbox
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Set CT = ...` requires a `ChartTitle` object on the right side while [`InputBox()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251811.aspx) function returns a `String`

moreover `ActiveChart`.[`ChartObjects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821276(v=office.15).aspx) *"Returns an object that represents either a single embedded chart (a ChartObject object) or a collection of all the embedded charts (a ChartObjects object) on the sheet."*, of which is not what you want to set a chart title...

rather, you want to set `Text` property of `ChartTitle` object retrieved with `ChartTitle` property of the relevant `Chart` object.

and I'd prefer [`Application.InputBox()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx) method rather than VBA `InputBox()` function in that the former lets you force the user input type by its `Type` parameter: 
setting it to `2` will force a string input.

finally before assigning `Selection` to a `Range` object always check the former really *is* a `Range` object

so here what you could go with:

```
'Change Data source to currentley selected cells
If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if selection is not a 'Range (i.e. it might be a 'Chart')
Set rng = Selection '<--| now you can do that safely

'Add a chart onto the active sheet and select the chart
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

With ActiveChart
    'Chart type is Clustered Column chart
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered

    'Add user data to create a chart title
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = Application.InputBox("Please enter a chart title", "Chart Title Name", Type:=2)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

with yourobject.chart

```
  .SetElement  msoElementChartTitleAboveChart 

  .ChartTitle.Caption = Title$
```

end with